# Change row color using Google spreadsheet API

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'd like to change the row color of a **spreadsheet** using the Google [Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).

I'm using **JAVA**, I saw it working in **JavaScript** but I don't found it in **JAVA**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Set cell color:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String)

google-apps-script (JavaScript) is the only option as far as I know. It can't be done with the spreadsheet-API (gdata)

Answer (score 5):

Google Sheet API Documentation is not the best to say the least but after some fiddling here is python code that works:

```
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
discovery_url = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                 'version=v4')
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url, cache_discovery=False)

spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=ss.id).execute()

requests = []

for sheet in spreadsheet.get('sheets'):
    sheetId = sheet.get('properties').get('sheetId')
    requests.append({
            "updateCells": {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "values": [{
                                   "userEnteredFormat": {
                                       "backgroundColor": {
                                           "red": 1,
                                           "green": 0,
                                           "blue": 0,
                                           "alpha": 1
                                       }}}
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "fields": 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor',
            "range": {
                "sheetId": sheetId,
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "endRowIndex": 1,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endColumnIndex": 1
            }}})

    body = {
        'requests': requests
    }

    response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=ss.id, body=body).execute()
```

Comment: This only seems to change the background of a single cell. Even updating the `endColumnIndex` to a value > 1, it still only updates a single cell for me.

Comment: Not sure if this is a Java API vs. .NET API, but I ended up having to use `RepeatCellRequest` instead of `UpdateCellRequest`, as in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42926565/213902).

Answer (score 3):

With JavaScript API you could use this:

```
    const range = {
      sheetId: 250062959, // find your own
      startRowIndex: 0,
      endRowIndex: 1,
      startColumnIndex: 0,
      endColumnIndex: 1,
    };

    const request = {
      spreadsheetId, // fill with your own
      resource: {
        requests: [
          {
            updateCells: {
              range,
              fields: '*',
              rows: [
                {
                  values: [
                    {
                      userEnteredValue: { stringValue: 'message' },
                      userEnteredFormat: {
                        backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0 },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    try {
      const result = await client.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      throw `update row error ${error}`;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a long time since you originally asked but according to the v4 API you could technically set a conditional format that is always true with `spreadsheets.batchUpdate`

eg. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting

May not be the easiest thing to manage but is 'technically' possible

Answer (score 2):

```
object = {     
"updateCells": {
   "range": {
        "sheetId": sheetId,     
         "startRowIndex":startRowIndex,
         "endRowIndex": endRowIndex,     
         "startColumnIndex": startColumnIndex,                 
         "endColumnIndex": endColumnIndex     
        }
  "rows": [{
      "values": [{
          "textFormatRuns": [      
              {"format": {     
                "foregroundColor": {      
                   "red": 0.0,     
                   "green": 255.0,     
                   "blue": 31.0     
                },     
             },"startIndex": 0      
         },     
       ]     
     }     
    ]     
  }]
"fields": "textFormatRuns(format)"     
}     }
```