# How do I format a header row in Google Sheets API v4 in C#?

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want the following output:

[image]

But I receive the following result:

[image]

I followed the instructions on this SO question:

[How to Change color of range in google sheets api v4 in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348237/how-to-change-color-of-range-in-google-sheets-api-v4-in-net)

But this code is bold on all rows and columns of the sheet.

How can I solve this problem?
My Code is:

```
var userEnteredFormat = new CellFormat()
{
    TextFormat = new TextFormat()
    {
        Bold = true,
        FontSize = 12
    }
};

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchupdateCell = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();

//create the update request for cells from the first row
var updateCellsRequest = new Request()
{
    RepeatCell = new RepeatCellRequest()
    {
        Range = new GridRange()
        {
            SheetId = sheetId,
            StartColumnIndex = 0,
            StartRowIndex = 0,
            EndColumnIndex = 28,
            EndRowIndex = 1
        },
        Cell = new CellData()
        {
            UserEnteredFormat = userEnteredFormat
        },
        Fields = "UserEnteredFormat(TextFormat)"
    }
};

batchupdateCell.Requests = new List<Request>();
batchupdateCell.Requests.Add(updateCellsRequest);
SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest bur = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(batchupdateCell, SheetId);
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse responseUpdate3 = bur.Execute();
```

Comment: Show the code you are using here, in your question, along with the attempts you have made to modify it and the corresponding details of the results of those modifications.

Comment: please check my post again , i update it. please check the code

Comment: What have you attempted to modify in your code? What was the result?

Comment: this code bold all the data in spreedSheet which i have push, but i want only bold the header

Comment: I tried to remove the StartColumnIndex and EndColumnIndex but result was same

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine for me using the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/), which should translate almost 1:1 between the JSON POST body and the C#/Python/Java/... typed resource.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE:batchUpdate?
     fields=updatedSpreadsheet(sheets(data%2FrowData%2Fvalues%2FuserEnteredFormat%2Cproperties(sheetId%2Ctitle)))
```

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": YOUR_SHEET_ID_HERE,
                    "endRowIndex": 1
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat/textFormat",
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "textFormat": {
                            "bold": true,
                            "fontSize": 12
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "responseRanges": [
        "1:2"
    ],
    "includeSpreadsheetInResponse": true
}
```

[Demo link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate?spreadsheetId=YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE&fields=updatedSpreadsheet(sheets(data%252FrowData%252Fvalues%252FuserEnteredFormat%252Cproperties(sheetId%252Ctitle)))&_h=4&resource=%257B%250A++%2522requests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522repeatCell%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522range%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522sheetId%2522%253A+YOUR_SHEET_ID_HERE%252C%250A++++++++++%2522endRowIndex%2522%253A+1%250A++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++%2522fields%2522%253A+%2522userEnteredFormat%252FtextFormat%2522%252C%250A++++++++%2522cell%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522userEnteredFormat%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++%2522textFormat%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++%2522bold%2522%253A+true%252C%250A++++++++++++++%2522fontSize%2522%253A+12%250A++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%252C%250A++%2522responseRanges%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%25221%253A2%2522%250A++%255D%252C%250A++%2522includeSpreadsheetInResponse%2522%253A+true%250A%257D&)

The [`GridRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#GridRange) in my request identifies only the `sheetId` and the ending index, so it targets all columns in the given sheet, and formats only the first row. (an end index of 2 would format the 1st and 2nd rows unless the start index was given as 1, per the API spec).

For verification purposes, the demo link is configured to request that the Sheets API sends you back the [`TextFormat`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#TextFormat) of the first 2 rows on every sheet, along with the `title` and `sheetId` [`SheetProperties`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SheetProperties). Note that if no user format was applied to the second row, no data will be sent for it.